# Changing android actionbar button style

Tags: android, button, styles, android-actionbar

I'm currently changing the view on my `ActionBar` `MenuItem` like so:

```
MenuItem menuItem = menu.add(title);

TextView tv = new TextView(context);
tv.setTypeface(myTypeface);
tv.setText("hello");

menuItem.setActionView(tv);
```

However this disabled the function of the button, which I'm assuming is because I've changed the `ActionView`. Is there anyway I can do this whilst retaining the button function?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's an example of creating a custom `MenuItem` for the `ActionBar`.

**First**: Create the `View` that will serve as your `MenuItem`.

**ActionLayoutExample**

```
/**
 * A {@link RelativeLayout} that serves as a custom {@link MenuItem}
 */
public class ActionLayoutExample extends RelativeLayout {

    /** The MenuItem */
    private TextView mHello;

    /**
     * Constructor for <code>ActionLayoutExample</code>
     * 
     * @param context The {@link Context} to use
     * @param attrs The attributes of the XML tag that is inflating the view
     */
    public ActionLayoutExample(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        // Ensure the MenuItem is accessible
        CheatSheet.setup(this);
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    @Override
    protected void onFinishInflate() {
        super.onFinishInflate();
        // Initialize the TextView
        mHello = (TextView) findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
        mHello.setTypeface(myTypeface);
        mHello.setText("Hello");
    }

}
```

**Second**: Create the layout that you'll actually apply to the `MenuItem`.

**action_layout_example**

```
<your.package.name.ActionLayoutExample xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    style="?android:attr/actionButtonStyle"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:contentDescription="@string/hello_world" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@android:id/text1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</your.package.name.ActionLayoutExample>
```

It's important to include the style `style="?android:attr/actionButtonStyle"` to make sure the layout properly reflects `ActionBar` items. It's also important to include a `android:contentDescription` in your layout. Normally when you long press a `MenuItem` with an icon, a tooltip is shown to indicate what that `MenuItem` is for. In your case, you'll need to take an extra step to make sure this tooltip is still accessible.

A great helper for this is [Roman Nurik's CheatSheet](https://gist.github.com/romannurik/3982005). You can see how I'm using it in the constructor of the action layout.

You specifically asked about the `MenuItem` being selectable. To do this, make sure you include the `android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"` and `android:clickable="true"` attributes.

**Third**: Use the `android:actionLayout` attribute to set your layout and inflate the menu normally within your `Activity` or `Fragment`.

**your_menu**

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_typeface"
    android:actionLayout="@layout/action_layout_example"
    android:showAsAction="ifRoom"
    android:title="@string/hello_world"/>
```

**Using the `MenuItem`**

In `onCreateOptionsMenu` call `MenuItem.getActionView` and on `View.onClickListener`. This is because `onOptionsItemSelected` will not be called for a custom `View`

```
final View example = menu.findItem(R.id.action_typeface).getActionView();
example .setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // Do something
    }
});
```

**The results**

[image]

Comment: I forgot to mention that you need to call `MenuItem.getActionView` to actually use it. Sorry about that, I updated my response. Actually, I think that's what you were looking for all along. I guess I gave you longer answer than you bargained for.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
tv.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                //handle
            }
        });
```

Comment: i think i tried this already, i'll do it again and confirm. thanks though