# set actionbar icon height to match actionbar height

Tags: android, android-actionbar

see the problem here, the grey checkbox leaves room from the top and bottom of the action bar:
[image: small actionbar icon]

styles.xml

```
<resources xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<style name="CustomActionBarTheme" parent="Theme.Base.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
    <item name="android:actionButtonStyle">@style/ActionButtonStyle</item>
</style>

<!--<style name="ActionButtonStyle" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionButton">-->
<style name="ActionButtonStyle" >
    <item name="android:height">@dimen/abc_action_bar_default_height</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">@dimen/abc_action_bar_default_height</item>
</style>
```

i set the item like so:

```
getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.submit_action, menu);
```

submit_action looks like:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <item android:id="@+id/action_submit"
        android:icon="@drawable/check"
        app:showAsAction="always"  />
</menu>
```

and finally, attached is the @drawable/check being used.

[image]

any idea how i can get the check to fill the actionbar?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason your icon doesn't fill the `ActionBar` is due to how the [`ActionMenuItemView`](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/com/android/internal/view/menu/ActionMenuItemView.java) measures the icon.

The `ActionMenuItemView` invokes a [maximum size of `32dp`](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/com/android/internal/view/menu/ActionMenuItemView.java#L52) when it [sets the bounds for your icon](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/com/android/internal/view/menu/ActionMenuItemView.java#L167)

So, it makes so difference how large your image is, the system will always resize it.

> any idea how i can get the check to fill the actionbar?

You should use a action layout for your `MenuItem`, a check mark icon with no background, and change the background color of the action layout parent as you see fit. Here's an example:

**layout**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    style="?android:attr/actionButtonStyle"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#e8e8e8"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:contentDescription="@string/cd" >

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:contentDescription="@null"
        android:scaleType="centerInside"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_action_tick" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**MenuItem**

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_submit"
    android:actionLayout="@layout/your_action_layout"
    android:showAsAction="always"/>
```

**Accessibility**

It's important to make sure your `MenuItem` is accessible. Normally when you long press an item in the `ActionBar` a short `Toast` will display the content description for you, but when you're using a custom `MenuItem` it's up to you to implement this pattern. An easy way to do this is by using [Roman Nurik's CheatSheet](https://gist.github.com/romannurik/3982005). If you're unsure how to use it, you should refer to [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19572990/420015) that goes into much more detail on creating custom `MenuItem` layouts.

**Alternatively**

If you want to use that background color for every `MenuItem` you have, you could create a custom style and apply it using the `android:actionButtonStyle` attribute. Here's an example of that:

**Your style**

```
<style name="Your.ActionButton" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionButton">
    <item name="android:background">#e8e8e8</item>
</style>
```

**Your theme**

```
<style name="Your.Theme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light">
    <item name="android:actionButtonStyle">@style/Your.ActionButton</item>
</style>
```

**Results**

[image: Example]

Comment: what is ic_action_tick in your example?

Comment: i followed your code verbatim (with my styles changes above) the activity starts with the ellipsis, rather than a check in the actionbar.

Comment: aah, scrach that. i applied the ic_action_tick icon, but the actionbar shows nothing (just a white bar from left to right), but i know the menu item is there (clicking it brings up a toast as expected)

Comment: @tipu Well, I'm not sure what to tell you. You've got to be doing something differently. Did you forget to mention you're using AppCompat? Because in that case you'd need to use the support library attributes too.

Comment: i was using AppCompat (didn't realize it was important enough to mention, sorry). from another question, i realized it was because i used android:actionLayout instead of appp:actionLayout, but otherwise your advice was spot on

Answer (score -1):

Here's what I do with Icons in Android to get the sizing correct.  You have an existing project with the res/drawable- folders.  You have to put the correct Icon into the correct folder.

Start a new project wizard and when you get to the launcher icon put in the Icon you want to use in your existing project.  finish the wizard.  The wizard will make the various sizes of Icons for you.  Then I manually copy the Icons from the res/drawable-xdpi res/drawable-ldpi etc to the corresponding folder on my existing project.  Delete the new project it is no longer needed.

Comment: as a result they'll appear correctly in the actionbar? i have entered a massive checkbox picture, so picture should be over sized, why would it not fill the action bar?

Comment: The OS will at least have the correct sizes of Icons to choose from.  Whether it fills the actionbar has to do with actual Icon and it's blank space.  A good place to start is to down load the icons from developer.andoroid.com.  They are already properly sized and it the correct folders when you unzip the file.